# Plotting a variable that is within a hypergeometric function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, special-functions

I kindly ask for help with the following problem.

I have two equations. The first one is:

```
1/(p (1 + (-1 + n) r)) == 1/Hypergeometric2F1[1, k - n, k, q/(-1 + q)]
```

and the second one is the function f:

```
f[q_, n_, k_] := 
Sum[Binomial[n, t] q^t (1 - q)^(n - t), {t, k - 1, n}]
```

I am interested in plotting the values that f returns for a range of the parameters n, k, p, and r (which appear in the first equation).

So what I need is to solve the first equation for q and then substitute it for q in the function f. However, standard procedures in Mathematica cannot solve the equation due to the hypergeometric series.

Is there a way to achieve the plots that I want, even without doing the intermediate step (i.e. solving the first equation for q)?

I am grateful for any advice and recommendation!

EDIT:

Ranges of interest / assumptions are:

```
n: integer in the range from 0 to 20
k: integer in the range from 0 to 20 but k < n
p: p > 1
r: in the range from 0 to 1
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. For fixed `n, k, p`, and `r`, the first equation determines `q` uniquely. It is not an independent variable.

Comment: Then what kind of plot do you expect? for fixed `n, k, p`, and `r`, $\{f,q\}$ is a single point in the plane; not a curve. You don't have a range of `q` (as you say in the OP), but a single fixed value.

Comment: `FindRoot` seems to have little trouble getting a numerical value for `q` given a decent guess and numerical values for the other parameters.

Comment: Sorry I missspecified the question. Of course not plotting for a range of q but for a range of the other parameters!

Comment: Before anything else: what are the assumptions on `n,k,p,r`? Are they positive? Integers? Complex?

Comment: @John Doty: Thank you! Is there a way then to use FindRoot over a full range and not just a single value, as I would need to do it in a plotting command?

Comment: @JM: Sorry for not giving the information (my first post). I edited the question

Comment: If you want to plot `f` for a range of `n, k, p`, and `r`, you'll need a five-dimensional plot, which I assume is not what you want. Please, be more specific. What exactly do you want? a level set? for what independent variables?

Comment: OK, thank you for providing the assumptions. Now, note that your restriction `k < n` implies that your hypergeometric functions actually degenerate to polynomials.

Comment: I want to do multiple 2D or 3D plots. For example one would be, f as a function of r, for fixed n = 6, k = 4 and p = 1.5

Comment: Just to help things along, since I can't provide an answer for now: if you use the [Euler transformation](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/07/0002/), your equation simplifies to `p + (-1 + n) p r + (-1 + q) Hypergeometric2F1[1, n, k, q] == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick-and-dirty solution:

```
Manipulate[
    ListPlot[
        Table[{#, (1 - #)^(1 - k + n) #^(-1 + k) Binomial[n, -1 + k] Hypergeometric2F1[1, -1 + k - n, k, #/(# - 1)]} &@
            FindRoot[1/(p (1 + (-1 + n) r)) == 1/Hypergeometric2F1[1, k - n, k, q/(-1 + q)], {q, .5}][[1, 2]]
        , {r, 0.001, .999, .01}]
    , Joined -> True]
, {n, 3, 20, 1}, {k, 1, n - 1, 1}, {p, 1.01, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is pretty great, thank you a lot!